# Prove that $\mathcal U(\mu, \nu)$ is compact for the weak topology of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, compactness, optimal-transport

In the book Computational Optimal Transport, by Peyré and Cuturi, the following assertion is made.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two compact probability spaces, with $c$ continuous and
$$
\mathcal U(\mu, \nu):= \left\{
\gamma \in \mathcal P(X \times Y) \quad :  \quad 
(\text{Proj}_X)_\# \gamma = \mu,
(\text{Proj}_Y)_\# \gamma = \nu 
\right\}
$$

The author then claims that $\mathcal U(\mu, \nu)$ is compact for the weak topology of measures.

How does one proves this assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are X and Y considered to be Polish?

If yes: every probability measure on a Polish space is tight. Using this you can show that $\mathcal{U}(\mu,\nu)$ is also tight. By Prokhorov's Theorem its closure is compact. Using how $\mathcal{U}(\mu,\nu)$ is defined you can show that it is closed w.r.t. the weak topology and therefore it is compact.